# Find available days within a date range

Tags: javascript, algorithm, date

Let's say there's a system that shows date availability for events. We have a main date range where all events go. Events can be date ranges themselves too.

Example:

```
[Date X]========================================[Date Y]
        [A]=====[A]        [B]=====[B][C]=====[C]
        [ Event A ][ Open ][ Event B ][ Event C ]
```

Where Date X and Date Y are the main date range where events go. And A,B, and C are events that have been scheduled.

How can I efficiently retrieve the open date range?

Example 2:

```
var rangeStart = new Date("04-01-2016");
var rangeEnd = new Date("04-31-2016");

var eventAStart = new Date("04-01-2016");
var eventAEnd = new Date("04-06-2016");

var eventBStart = new Date("04-15-2016");
var eventBEnd = new Date("04-30-2016");
```

I need to return something like:

```
var availableRangeStart = "04-07-2015";
var availableRangeEnd = "04-14-2016";
```

because these are the dates in the main range that are not overlapped by "event" ranges.

To be exact on what I am trying to do:

My app is a trip planner where the user sets the dates for their trip and then adds different destinations to that trip that have their own dates. (User is going on a trip to Europe April 1st to April 30th, they will be in Paris on April 1st to April 6, then they will be in London April 15th to April 30th). But the user has not planned anything from April 7th to April 14th. I am trying to return these dates so that when they add a new destination, the dates are pre-filled.

Comment: I don't really get what you mean

Comment: @YehiaAwad Sorry, I should have been more clear. Lets say for the Month of April there are 3 events scheduled. Event A is April 1st - April 6th, Event B is April 15th - April 20th and Event C is April 21st - April 30th. I need to retrieve April 7th - April 14th (because no events are scheduled).

Comment: If you can clarify, then please do so by editing your question. Can you also provide the code you have tried with; the data structure with sample data?

Comment: Are events always non-overlapping in time? What format do you use for dates? Date objects?

Comment: @trincot I have added some code examples. I'm not too concerned about formats and syntax (if it doesn't make it easier to solve) I'm looking for the logic to go about this. I appreciate your help! Events can overlap.

Comment: Yet another downvote without an explanation - people should write why it's downvoted to improve the quality of the site - not just increase frustration and generate guessing games.

Comment: @cbronson Thank you for your patience and your edits. Your problem is well described and I find it challenging. I posted an answer bellow. Hope it would help you! PS: I like your schema in ASCII. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that returns from/to periods that are free:

```js
// Helper function
function addDays(date, days) {
    return new Date(date.getTime() + days * 24*60*60*1000);
}

// Main function
function gaps(period, events) {
    events = events.slice(0).filter(function (a) {
        // Exclude events which are outside the main period
        return a.to >= period.from && a.from <= period.to;
    }).sort(function (a, b) {
        // Sort events by their starting date
        return a.from - b.from;
    });
    var result = events.reduce(function (result, curr) {
        if (curr.from - result.free > 0) {
            // gap found
            result.gaps.push({
                from: result.free, 
                to:   addDays(curr.from, -1)
            });
        }
        if (curr.to - result.free >= 0) {
            // first free day is after this event
            result.free = addDays(curr.to, 1)
        }
        return result;
    }, { gaps: [], free: period.from } );
    // Potentially add gap between last event end period-end
    if (period.to - result.free >= 0) {
        result.gaps.push({
            from: result.free,
            to:   period.to
        });
    }
    return result.gaps;
}


// Sample data:

var period = {
    from: new Date('2016-01-01'),
    to: new Date('2016-12-31')
};

var events = [
    { from: new Date('2016-02-01'), to: new Date('2016-02-29') },
    { from: new Date('2016-03-01'), to: new Date('2016-03-15') },
    { from: new Date('2016-04-16'), to: new Date('2016-04-30') },
];

// Call to function
var res = gaps(period, events);

// Output in snippet
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(res, null, 4));
```

Answer (score 2):

I just give you an algorithm because the final implementation depends of your code.

```
var aprilAvailableDays = [true, true, true, etc...] // a boolean for each day

aprilEvents.forEach(function (event) {
    for (var i = event.startDay; i <= event.endDay; i++) {
        aprilAvailableDays[i] = false;
    }
});
```

Comment: The simplest solution is often also the easiest.  Populate an array of all available dates and as each date is entered, mark the date as unavailable if it sits in the range being added.  You can pre-check if any of those dates is already occupied before adding it.  Simple and elegant.

Comment: Wow, I was really overthinking this. Thanks so much for your help!